# Memory leak when using custom generator in Keras

Tags: memory-leaks, keras

My problem is memory leak. Note:"GPU memory is no problem."

Environment:

> Using Theano backend.
>   Keras==1.1.1, Theano==0.9.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.
>   16GB RAM and SWAP.
>   GPU: GTX1080

For the multiple outputs, the code at training was designed by oneself.
Look at the following function and training code.

Function:

```
def customGenerator(X,Y1,Y2):
    while True:
        idx = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
        datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
        batches = datagen.flow( X[idx], batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
        labels = [Y1[idx],Y2[idx]]
        idx0 = 0
        for batch in batches:
            idx1 = idx0 + batch.shape[0]
            yield batch, [labels[0][idx0:idx1],labels[1][idx0:idx1]]
            idx0 = idx1
            if idx1 >= X.shape[0]
                break
```

Training Code:

```
model.fit_generator(customGenerator(X_train,Y_train,Y_train2),
                    samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]
                    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                    validation_data=customGenerator(X_val,Y_val,Y_val2),
                    nb_val_samples=X_val.shape[0],
                    verbose=1)
```

When training the network, it proceeded to 6 epochs and caused a memory error.
Observing the state of the memory showed that the memory usage rate increased as the epoch progressed.

I think there is a problem with the custom function, but I can not find where the problem is.

Could you help me?

Comment: why are your Y labels in a list of np arrays?

Comment: In this? -->labels = [Y1[idx],Y2[idx]]  It is my hobit.  It is certainly not necessary.

Comment: No in yield, you return a list of two arrays... Can they just be concatinated

Comment: The arrays can't be concatenated. I have 2 types of labels. That's why I use a multiple output model.

Comment: Ok I believe the problem is the use of `ImageDataGenerator` which you are using as a generator in a generator. Why dont you just use it as its used in the [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)??

Comment: I agree with that your opinion that there is the problem "generator in a generator". In that [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator), when using `imageDataGenerator`, it is written as `model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),steps_per_epoch=len(x_train), epochs=epochs)`.However, `datagen.flow(x,y)` is not accepted the multiple labels...